# Deploying Windows Forms Application Using ClickOnce From a Website URL Is Creating 2 New Application Folders on my PC Rather Than 1 Folder

Tags: winforms, clickonce

When I install my Windows Forms application from a website URL using ClickOnce it is creating 2 new folders rather than the expected 1 folder in the following path...

C:\Users\UsernameABC\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\xxxxxx\xxxxxx

Folder A is called...
abc..tion_783304b0b3cc9a77_0001.0000_53873b5b1073b86f
and Folder B is called...
abc...exe_783304b0b3cc9a77_0001.0000_none_a7f40ca211c829dc

Folder A has all of the compiled files, rescource files, config files and manifest files

Folder B just has the rescource files, config files and manifest files but no compiled files

I have pasted images of the folders below and the parent folder (Folder C).

Why is it creating two application folders ?

[Folder A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgjwy.jpg)

[Folder B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaD5z.jpg)

[Folder C - Parent Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yjlkb.jpg)

Thank you in advance.

Will

Comment: Try [Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/) to create an installer for Winforms applications.

Comment: I have answered this question, can you mark it as an answer if you found this helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/) to create an installer for Winforms applications.